# Global Variable

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I have the following problem: I want to create a product catalogue. In the catalogue there are different types (Content Types) of products: eg chairs, tables, couches (i approached that with content types and taxonomy terms).
How can I implement a "switch" button, that switches between private customers and business clients. I think there should be a checkboxfield in the content type, so i can define, that a certain chair is visible for business or for private or for all clients.
How can I filter this information?
How can I display these items in a menu?
Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Permissions dude...

Answer (score 0):

You have so many ways to do this :) 
I guess the smartest would be to create a taxonomy vocabulary with only two terms.

Or you could have a simple "text field / multiple choices" field.

But taxonomy would be smarter I guess.